# Mysql datetime to Calendar

Tags: java, date, jdbc

My code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
c.setTime(res.getDate("my_date")); //res is ResultSet

System.out.println(c.getTime());
System.out.println(res.getString("my_date"));
```

Output:

```
Thu Oct 11 00:00:00 IST 2012 
2012-10-11 02:50:00.0
```

In calendar, it is not considering the time part. I used Calendar because I have to make some comparisons.

Why time part is omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
out.println(sdf.format(rs.getTimestamp("your_date_field").getTime()));
```

By the way, you have to create a SimpleDateFormat that fit your SQL date format.

Comment: output: `2012-10-11 24:00:00`. Still time part is not working.

Comment: oops see my edit, you have to use getTimeStamp, getDate only return the date (without time) part.